# Pros and Cons of addressing users by their name in Login header links

Tags: usability, login

What are the pros and cons of header Login links with the following message:

1. Login
2. Login, [First Name]

I remember reading that addressing users by their first name is overall more friendly and targeted. However, I cannot find those studies.

Could you point me to any research regarding addressing users by their first names?

Thanks!

Comment: Curious...how do you track a user account to a computer accessing your site but not logged in? I'm wondering about public computers, etc.

Comment: Accounts are automatically logged out after X time (this is outside of our control). We still know who they are based on cookies.

Comment: "We still know who they are based on cookies _if they don't block them before or delete them afterwards_." FTFY

Answer (score 5):

**Don't use Login, [First name].**

1. It's a mixed signal. The system is communicating that it both knows and does not know who the user is.
2. "Login" is a command, and this command is being given to one and only one person. If you're Nicolas and the command is "Login, Anna", then you might feel like only Anna is allowed to login.
3. It's definitely a good practice to show the user's name or username after they've logged in, as an authentication success signal. If you show it both before and after login, an unauthenticated user might think they're already logged in.

Answer (score 1):

No research, just experience.

#### Pro

Different logins (e.g. admin/personal) to the same app in different browsers on the same machine. But then it's usually the user/profile name, not the real first name.

#### Con

Users using their laptops/notebooks/mobiles/cells in the public which potentially exposes their name to strangers.

Answer (score 0):

**There are no pros and cons**, it's just a matter of **taste**, the users already know where they are (previous registration). It can be a generic message (welcome back) or a personal greeting. It doesn't matter when the user is registered, however when the user is not registered and you use third party login prompts it is quite intrusive, and should be only shown when attempting to access members area or clicking the Login/Register button.